# How to properly compute Web API methods URLs in TypeScript within ASP.NET Core 1.1. solution?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, iis-8, visual-studio-2017, typescript2.0

I am trying to set up a Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core 1.1 solution to work with an Angular2 SPA.

I have created a sample `csproj` using the following commands:

```
npm install -g yo generator-aspnetcore-spa
yo aspnetcore-spa
```

and then opened it in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

When running using IIS Express 10, it works fine (routing, refresh, Web API calls). However, when deploying within a Web Application under IIS, Web API calls fails due to path not containing Web application name:

fetchdata.component.ts file defines data fetch as follows:

```
constructor(http: Http) {
    http.get('/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts').subscribe(result => {
        this.forecasts = result.json() as WeatherForecast[];
    });
}
```

This works fine in IIS Express, as path `http://localhost:port/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts` is correct. However, this fails under IIS because the correct path is:

```
http://localhost:port/ApplicationName/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts
```

Hardcoding application name in URL works, but this is not a viable solution.

I have changed _Layout.cshtml to properly set base (path), but it does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
@{ 
    string basePath = Url.Content("~");
}
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplicationBasic</title>
        <base href="@basePath" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </head>
    <body>
        Base path: @basePath

        @RenderBody()

        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

If I understood correctly, the path is assumed to be relative to `tsconfig.json` file which is placed outside wwwroot folder. That would explain why all path from js generated from ts do not take web application folder into account.

**Question:** How can I dynamically specify URL prefix for calls with TypeScript files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a relative path instead of absolute path. Just remove the `/` from your `http.get(...)` calls.

You have already correctly set up the base path (which also works easier by doing `<base href="~/"/>`). This will make sure that the base path is always used as starting point for relative urls. This also applies to ajax calls. All new browsers already support `<base href=""/>`. Also see my former post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41715462/455493).

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you! I had two mistakes in my code: `<base href="@basePath" />` should be `<base href="@basePath/" />` or `<base href="~/"/>` and remove the extra `/` as you mentioned.